# Upsert multiple documents into mongoDB

Tags: arrays, mongodb, upsert

I have a **array** of values, some of the values in the **array** may already be present in my database. I want to `upsert` the new values and *increase the count* of the old values. 
One way to do this is :

- For all the values that are present in the database use a update command and increment count. It can be done using : `db.test.update({ link: {$in: ["A", "B"]}}, {$inc: {count: 1}}, {upsert: true, multi:true})`
- For all the values not present in my database, check each and every value and upsert it into the database.

The second step may put some load on the network. Is there any way to do the second step in one command?

**For example consider this**:

*Initial state of my database*:

```
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5a45f97f84527190e1f28cb7"), "link" : "A", "count" : 3 }
```

and I have the array as following: `const values = ['A', 'B', 'C']`

Now I want to have something like this:

```
{"_id": ObjectId("abc"), "link": "A", "count" : 4},
{"_id": ObjectId("xyz"), "link": "B", "count" : 1},
{"_id": ObjectId("fgh"), "link": "C", "count" : 1}
```

Comment: the second step you are mentioning is done in the by enabling upsert to true in the update query in just one command, isn't it?  i don't understand your question

Comment: @divine For every value I would have to check whether it exists in the database or not, if it doesn't I would have to insert that value as a new document. But since there are a lot of documents I would like to insert, I was thinking if there is something like `insertMany()`, that would upsert all values from the array.
Please refer the example I have given.

Comment: @divine In the second step, if I use the `update()` command, then it requires **a single query** and would update many documents that are already present in the document, or it would insert a single one. What I want is, I want to insert many documents, depending on their existence in the database(if present increase count, insert it otherwise).

Answer (score 0):

To achieve the second step (as you mentioned) optimally you can perform lookup in your `DB` using `find()` method.

If the array value isn't present in the `DB`, then find() is gonna return an empty object. So you just see the length of the object returned from `find()`. If found empty, insert into `DB` else update the info.

Example code for `nodejs` environment:

```
var db = mongojs('dbname', ['collection_name']);

var theLink = 'XYZ';

db.collection_name.find({link: theLink}, function (err, obj) {
    if (err)
        throw err;
    if (obj.length == 0)
        // write logic to insert
    else
        // write logic to update
});
```